# regex, delete first part of a string

Tags: php, regex

I have the string `562865_numbersletterssymbols`

If I want to delete, IF EXISTS; the first part (562865_), what should I search?

My guess was `^[^?:(562865_)]+$` to take what was not "562865_" (if existing `?:`) until $ `+$`

But I discovered that (562865_) searchs every single digit and not the whole string.

How can I find the solution?

Comment: What language are you using? Why use `Regex` for this?

Comment: are you looking specifically for the exact sequence "562865_" or any set of numbers, followed by an underscore?

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but why not find "562865_" in the target string, and then replace the match(if any) with an empty string? I would prefer this approach to finding what's "not" 562865_

Comment: `$your_var = str_replace('562865_', '', $your_var)`, no? Sorry for not posting this as an answer, but I can't believe in this question being _extremely_ localized.

Comment: I can't believe I am that idiot, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way that I was able to come up with is this. It will work not only for that name but any others with the same format.

```
<?php
$string = "562865_numbersletterssymbols";

echo preg_replace("/^\d+_/", "", $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with regex, try `^[\d]+_(.+)$`

the `_` splits the string into 2 parts, and you need the second part in parenthesis `(.+)`

Comment: `[\d]` - why you put a character class into a character class?

Comment: I'd have problems if I don't find that exact initial part, because it will strip away a lot more of the string, till the first "_"

Comment: @user1722791 if your initial part is always 562865_, how about `^562865_(.+)$` ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to raina77ow, the easiest way is always the best choice.

```
$your_var = str_replace('562865_', '', $your_var)
```